# jquery.data: How to store a data to an element and access it?

Tags: jquery, data-binding, jquery-1.9

How can I store a data to an element and then manipulate that check if it has the data?

For instance I have these two elements with the same class name.

```
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
```

jquery,

```
$(".elem:first").data("hasdata","popup");

if($(".elem").data("hasdata") === 'popup') $(".elem").css({background:'red'})
```

I get two red but I just want the first one to turn red. Is it possible?

my test on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBhTf/)

Comment: `$(".elem")` will select all elements with a class of `elem`, it will not filter to only the one that has data unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `each` to iterate over all elements with the class `elem`

```
$(".elem:first").data("hasdata","popup");
$(".elem").each(function(){
  if ($(this).data("hasdata") === 'popup'){
    $(this).css({background:'red'});
  }
});
```

check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBhTf/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter() and put condition in it.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YfLAW/)**

```
$(".elem:first").data("hasdata","popup");
$(".elem").filter(function(){
    return $(this).data("hasdata");
}).css({background:'red'});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$(".elem:first").attr("data-hasdata","popup");

$(".elem[data-hasdata='popup']").css({background:'red'});
```

**[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f3BCw/)**